# Hiding module imports in package

Tags: python

I have a small package that has a few dependencies such as pandas and gensim.  The file structure is like so

```
/package
    __init__.py
    agg_clean.py
```

In the `__init__.py` file, I have `import agg_clean` so I am able to access the functions in a chained manner, e.g.:

```
import package as pkg
pkg.agg_clean.function()
```

However, I have a couple of import statements in `agg_clean.py`, (pandas, os, etc.).  when I do a chained import as above, I am also able to access the imports in `agg_clean`, e.g. `pkg.agg_clean.os.listdir()`

How can I hide imports from my various modules in the package import?

Comment: Accessing `os` via `pkg.agg_clean` doesn't seem so bad or dangerous to me. Why not just let your users go ahead and do that, if they really want to?

Comment: I'm fine for dev purposes, but I wouldn't want users to have any weird namespace collisions if they are using this package and the actual OS module.  Beyond that, I just don't like it from a stylistic standpoint...

Comment: That seems worse (as mentioned).  Is there some way for me to place my imports in __init__.py?  It seems most of the well-known modules that I've used don't seem to have this problem.  could I restructure the package with subdirectories for each module?

Comment: What about importing the module or function/method from the module inside the necessary functions defined in the modules in your package?

Answer (score 5):

**tl;dr**: *You can't cleanly.* Or more accurately, you shouldn't be worried about things like this.

There's no `namespace collisions` in this case, since the os module is loaded under then name `pkg.agg_clean.os`. If the user wants to use your imported os package, there is no harm in letting them do that. On top of that, there's no *good* way to prevent them from doing that.

There's something interesting to remember here. Take the following python module that can be imported by another python script:

```
# module_im_importing.py
import os as _os

__all__ = ["echo"]

name_not_available = 'some_constant_string'

def echo(object):
    pass
```

If your user imports the bare module using `import module_im_importing`, all defined variables are made available to their environment under the name `module_im_importing`.

```
>>> import module_im_importing
>>> dir()  # Lookup local namespace
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'module_im_importing']
>>> dir(module_im_importing)  # See defined items in your package.
['__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'echo', 'name_not_available', 'os']
```

If they instead `from module_im_importing import *`  (which is discouraged), the behavior is a little different:

```
>>> from module_im_importing import *
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'echo']
```

This causes the names defined in the file `module_im_importing.py` to be imported into the user's local namespace. Because we used `__all__` in your module, only the items defined in `__all__` are imported to the users local namespace from your module. This can pollute their namespace if, for example, you've defined a function like `echo` which conflicts with another package they may be using.

This is why Wildcard imports are clearly frowned upon in [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports). From the document:

`Wildcard imports (from <module> import *) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools.`

In any case, please don't worry yourself over things like this. It's only an issue if the user of your module doesn't follow PEP8, and they should probably be shown the errors of their ways anyway. Remember, in Python, `We're all consenting adults here`.

Answer (score 0):

This is really just a side-effect of the way that python modules work.  Anything that you import into a module will be available as a top-level object in that module.  Most people don't worry about it and simply use the canonical import path.