# Import specific names only

Tags: python, import, module, package

I have the following package structure:

```
analysis/
         __init__.py
         main.py
         utils/
               __init__.py
               myzip.py
```

`myzip.py` contains the following:

```
import pandas
def save():
    ...
def load():
    ...
```

In my `main.py` script I do:

`from utils import myzip`

and when I type `myzip.<TAB>` or do `dir(myzip)` the imported `pandas` appears as well. **Can I avoid showing the `pandas` imported in the submodule?** Is there a best practice for importing third party modules?

---

I tried adding the following to `analysis/utils/__init__.py`:

```
from utils.myzip import save, load
```

but it still shows `pandas` when I `dir(myzip)` form `main.py`.

Looking at [`from sklearn import cluster`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/tree/master/sklearn/cluster) they manage to achieve this, without showing all the `numpy` imports they have e.g. in [`cluster/k_means_.py`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py)

Comment: If your save and load functions depend on pandas, then doesn't it make sense that your programs needs to be able to access pandas regardless of where it tries to execute the save and load functions?

Comment: Where is the `dir(utils)` being executed? None of your sample code imports `utils`.

Comment: @martineau Thanks for pointing this out, that was a typo. If I do import `utils` and <tab> it, then I get `save`, `load` and `myzip` as suggestions. This is close to my solution of nesting into a folder with the drawback that I want to use `myzip.save()` instead of `utils.save()`.

Comment: Your sklearn example is not parallel.  You are importing `cluster`, not `k_means_`, so you only see names in `cluster`, and `cluster` doesn't import `np` from `k_means_`.  If you do `from sklearn.cluster import k_means_` you will see that `k_means_.np` is indeed available.  You can easily achieve that with a solution along the lines of the one you posted.

Comment: There are several questions that I think are duplicates of this, for instance [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516405/hiding-module-imports-in-package) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509012/hide-external-modules-when-importing-a-module-e-g-regarding-code-completion).  Please clarify what you're asking that isn't addressed there.

Comment: @BrenBarn Thanks for the links! Definitely answer my question, especially the second one. You can flag this question as duplicate, or you can answer reshuffling the asnwers in the two links. I did not find those answers because I did not think of the problem as **hiding** the module imports from the package.

Comment: @Oleg: The question can't be closed because it has a bounty.  I made an answer combining the information from the two questions I linked, plus some advice of my own.

Answer (score 2):

As described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46204969/hyperlinks-in-a-pandas-dataframe-in-python), you can import the modules with an alias that begins with an underscore (e.g., `import pandas as _pandas`).  The name will still be available as `myzip._pandas`, but IPython tab-completion will not autocomplete it (unless you explicitly type the underscore first).  Also, it will not be imported if you do `from myzip import *`, although you shouldn't do that anyway.

However, as mentioned in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516405/hiding-module-imports-in-package), the better "solution" is to just not worry about it.  If someone does `import myzip`, it does no harm for them to be able to access `myzip.pandas`; it's not like they couldn't import `pandas` themselves anyway.  Also, there is no risk of a name conflict in this situation, since `pandas` is namespaced under your module.  The only way a name conflict could arise is if your module itself used the name `pandas` for two different things (e.g., defining a global variable called `pandas` in addition to the imported module); but this is a problem internal to your module, regardless of whether `pandas` is externally accessible.

A name conflict can arise if someone has their own variable called `pandas` and then does `from myzip import *`, but star import is discouraged for precisely that reason, and the names of imported modules are no different than other names in this regard.  For instance, someone doing `from myzip import *` could face a conflict with the names `save` or `load`.  There's no use in worrying specifically about imported module names when it comes to star-import name conflicts.

Also, it's worth noting that many widely-used libraries expose their own imports in this way, and it's not considered a problem.  Pandas itself is an example:

```
>>> import pandas
>>> pandas.np
<module 'numpy' from '...'>
```

. . . so you are in good company if you just consider it a non-problem.

Answer (score 1):

If `moduleB` is imported at the module-level of `moduleA`, then `moduleB` is part of the namespace of `moduleA`.

One way to hide it however would be to import it with an alias:

```
import pandas as _hidden_pandas
```

It would then appear as `_hidden_pandas`, hiding it to some extent.
The tab-completion would at least not find it.

Answer (score 0):

#### A partial solution

Nest the submodule into a folder and import only the necessary methods in the `__init__.py`, that is:

```
analysis/
         __init__.py
         main.py
         utils/
               __init__.py
-->            myzip/
                     __init__.py
                     myzip.py
```

where the `myzip/__init__.py` has:

`from .myzip import load, save`

then after `from utils import myzip` the `dir(myzip)` will list `load`, `save` and `myzip`, but not the `pandas`, which is hidden inside `myzip.myzip.<TAB>`.

Have not figured out how `sklearn` hide their third party modules.