# Hyperlinks in a Pandas Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe

I have the following bit of code:

```
class summary_tables():
    def create_table(self, summary):
        formatting = formatter()
        table = pybloqs.HTMLJinjaTableBlock(summary,formatters=formatting.summary_format(), use_default_formatters=False)
        final_summary = pybloqs.VStack([table])
        return final_summary

class formatter():
    def summary_format(self):
        table_center = pybloqs.FmtAlignTable(alignment='center')
        align_cells = pybloqs.FmtAlignCellContents(alignment='center', apply_to_header_and_index=False)
        header = pybloqs.FmtHeader(fixed_width='auto', column_width='5cm', index_width='1cm', top_padding='2cm')
        heatmap1 = pybloqs.FmtHeatmap(axis=1, max_color=colors.HEATMAP_RED, min_color=colors.HEATMAP_RED, threshold=0.01)
        return [table_center, align_cells, header, heatmap1]
```

This is to help me build and format a html file from a `Pandas dataframe` called `summary_df`:

```
        mkt    price_diff
    0   APPL   '<a href="http://~price/APPL_breakdown.html">3</a>' 
    1   GOOG   '<a href="http://~price/GOOG_breakdown.html">0</a>'
    2   MSFT   '<a href="http://~price/MSFT_breakdown.html">2</a>'
```

So when I run:

```
tables = summary_tables()
summary_block = tables.create_table(summary_df)
file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname('/home/jbloggs/'), 'Summary.html')
block_final = pybloqs.VStack([summary_block])
block_final.save(file)
```

I see everything I expect when I open up the `html` file apart from the highlighting.. Looking at `def summary_format()` in my `class formatter()` you can see I'm trying to build a heatmap:

```
heatmap1 = pybloqs.FmtHeatmap(axis=1, max_color=colors.HEATMAP_RED, min_color=colors.HEATMAP_RED, threshold=0.01)
```

Problem is.. my `DatFrame` attaches the number to the hyperlink:

```
'<a href="http://~price/APPL_breakdown.html">3</a>'`
```

Here you can see that the link to the `APPL_breakdown.html` file is linked to the number `3`..

How can I resolve this so that the formatter function knows to look at the number rather than the hyperlink??

Comment: Can you post the minimal verifiable code so that we can reproduce your issue? For e.g. you didn't import pyblogs so I don't know which package you are referring to. If you are extracting it from a website, I'd usually recommend BeautifulSoup..

Answer (score 0):

I once achieved something very similar by splitting the task into two steps:

1) In the raw dataframe, have only the numerical value. Then the heatmap formatter should pick it up easily.

2) Then change the cell contents to a string in a separate formatter that combines the cell value (the number) with the hyperlink. This is similar to converting a float to a pretty-printed format, so you could use e.g. `FmtDecimals` as a template (see [this](https://github.com/manahl/PyBloqs/blob/master/pybloqs/block/table_formatters.py#L193-L199)).

Since your convert-to-hyperlink formatter is quite specific to your application, you can keep that formatter code local in your module and you do not need to modify pybloqs itself. Just add the formatter to the end of the list of formatters. This is necessary since it will modify the cell contents, again similar to the formatters for pretty-printing floats.

Comment: If you add some code to your answer, it will be much more useful!